# VB.NET - Stored procedure runs but parameters aren't working

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I have the following bit of code:

```
Dim SQLCon As New SqlConnection
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
Dim ds As New DataSet

SQLCon.ConnectionString = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("myConnString")
SQLCon.Open()
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

'run the stored procedure based on the view selected
If rdolstView.Items(0).Selected Then
    cmd = New SqlCommand("spCondensedView", SQLCon)
ElseIf rdolstView.Items(1).Selected Then
    cmd = New SqlCommand("spExtendedView", SQLCon)
End If

'filter by what the user searched for
If ddlSearchBy.SelectedValue = "Member" Then
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MbrNum", txtSearchFor.Text)
ElseIf ddlSearchBy.SelectedValue = "Assistant" Then
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AssignedAsst", ddlUWAssistants.SelectedValue)
ElseIf ddlSearchBy.SelectedValue = "Rep" Then
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rep", txtSearchFor.Text)
ElseIf ddlSearchBy.SelectedValue = "Dept Assistant" Then
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeptAsst", txtSearchFor.Text)
ElseIf ddlSearchBy.SelectedValue = "Creator" Then
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Creator", txtSearchFor.Text)
End If

Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
da.Fill(ds)
SQLCon.Close()
```

My problem is that the parameters don't seem to be working. Both stored procedures are supposed to take the optional parameter (either `@MbrNum`, `@AssignedAsst`, `@Rep`, `@DeptAsst`, or `@Creator`) and filter by it in its `WHERE` clause.

I've confirmed that this is working properly when I run the stored procedures manually in SQL Server Management Studio. I've also confirmed that the `If`/`ElseIf` statements are validating as true properly. So my code is definitely hitting the `AddWithValue()` statements when it's supposed to.

My returned result, however, is the full dataset without the filters applied, as if I ran the stored procedure with no parameters specified.

Any help would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Try specifying the `Command.Type`...For example: `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure`... By default it's set as `Text` I believe... Also wrap your connection and command's in `Using` statements so they are properly handled when done... Also do you your params in the stored proc defaulted?

Comment: Why are you using a replace like that? I suspect that is the problem. When you use parameters you don't need to replace single quotes with doubles. This has the appearance of code that recently was not using parameter but now is. Remove the Replace. Use sql profiler to see what is actually being passed. Also change the command type as zaggler suggested.

Comment: You should use breakpoint instead of throwning exception. But, I think it's because you do a replace ' with ''. You don't need to do that when using parameters. I assume you were concatenating before and decided to do it properly with parameter later on.

Comment: You guys are right about what I was doing. I was building the query manually and then it got a little unruly and it was moved to a stored procedure. I just forgot to remove the `Replace()`. I've corrected those issues and it hasn't solved my problem, though.

Comment: I've updated my code above to reflect the change.

Comment: @Steve - I don't get an error message at all. I just get the full dataset as if no parameters were specified.

Comment: Probably the problem is in the stored procedure. You should add the code of at least one of the sp.

Comment: @zaggler - your idea was pretty much right. My `cmd.CommandType` statement was in the wrong place. The `cmd = New SqlCommand("spCondensedView", SQLCon)` code was after it, resetting the CommandType back to text.

Comment: @zaggler - I'll give you answer credit if you want to throw your comment into an answer. Just specify where to put the code so some other schmuck doesn't make the same mistake I did. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying the a `Command.Type`...Set this when you create the command object.

```
 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
```

By default it's set as `Text` I believe... Also wrap your connection and command's in `Using` statements so they are properly handled when done...